# Choose form with radio button

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

Lets say I want to have multiple forms for a user to fill out, but first they must choose an option with a radio button.

This is extremely crude but will have to do for examples sake. 
When the user is on the page, they should only see a few radio buttons. (Male, Female, Dog, and Cat).

This is the example code for the available choices.

```
<fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="male" value="male"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="female" value="female"> Female
        <input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog"> Dog
        <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat"> Cat
 </fieldset>
```

When they select the radio button, that should open a few text forms for each radio selected. When the user fills out the next forms and submits the content, it should create a page for that user (basically a profile but this is just an example).

My question is: How do I make the forms available only after the radio is selected without opening a new page? and how would I go about making the automatic page part? 
I'd assume that it would be a mix of php and javascript if not more (I'm not the most advanced with those two). I appreciate the help and if I wasn't specific enough please tell me.

Comment: javascript in your flavor of choice,jquery is popular

Comment: Radio buttons are usually for a single option that a user chooses. If they can choose more than one, use checkboxes. It sounds like you don't need separate forms, just parts of your form inside divs, which you can show/hide with the checkboxes.

Comment: as stated, JS and Ajax would be lovely.

Comment: by the way, why the different name attributes for your radios? why not just give them the same name for gender and separate for the animal, and base yourself on the value(s)? using different name attributes only makes for bigger code for nothing really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it with pure CSS, using the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Achecked) and [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), with the caveat that the forms must be children of the same parent as the radio inputs. The trick is to set the initial `display` property of each form to `none`, resetting to `block` when the relevant input is selected.

For the sake of brevity, I've just styled the `form` tags in the following examples to be coloured blocks.

```css
form{
  display:none;
}
#input_male:checked~#form_male,
#input_female:checked~#form_female,
#input_dog:checked~#form_dog,
#input_cat:checked~#form_cat{
  display:block;
}
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#000;font-family:arial;}
input,label{display:inline-block;margin:0 0 10px;}
form{height:100px;}
form:first-of-type{background:red;}
form:nth-of-type(2){background:green;}
form:nth-of-type(3){background:blue;}
form:last-of-type{background:black;}
```

```html
<input name="form" id="input_male" type="radio" value="male">
<label for="input_male">Male</label>
<input name="form" id="input_female" type="radio" value="female">
<label for="input_female">Female</label>
<input name="form" id="input_dog" type="radio" value="dog">
<label for="input_dog">Dog</label>
<input name="form" id="input_cat" type="radio" value="cat">
<label for="input_cat">Cat</label>
<form id="form_male"></form>
<form id="form_female"></form>
<form id="form_dog"></form>
<form id="form_cat"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mihai said pure javascript or jQuery will help you. But about the idea:

You may have for example 3 steps of forms and based on users' chosses you may want to show different forms in second and third step. And other types of forms are hidden or will be created on web page using JavaScript/DOM And with JavaScript/jQuery event listeners you can find if its time to show the second layer form(a radio is selected etc.).

But its better that you use Ajax to get the second or third layer's form based on different answers user may give you(with selecting a radio etc.) . so you have a page php page that will give you the forms. Like `get_form.php` and you can send parameters to be the form you want based on data you get from user like `get_form.php?p1=3&p2=5` and you can add the HTML you get from `get_form.php` to empty tags you have in your page

Main.php

```
<HTML>
...
<script>
//codes to check if we need to show next form and code to get new forms with ajax
</script>
.....
<div I'd=form1container><form>
First layer form
</form></div>

<div I'd=form2container>
Second layer form container</div>

<div I'd=form3container>
Third layer form container</div>
```

get_form.php

```
echo "<form>";
// and different echoes based on parameters to create the dynamic form
echo "</form>
```